# How to disable wireless mouse dongle when not in use

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth, powertop

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have a Lenovo 500 Wireless Keyboard mouse combo. This comes with a small bluetooth dongle that I need to plug into the USB port.
I am only using this when in office but would like to have the dongle plugged in always as these things tend to loose.
The issue is that when I checked `powertop`, the dongle is the 2nd highest power consumer (even though I don't have the mouse and keyboard in range ). Is there any way I can selectively disable the USB dongle and enable it only when I am at office or when using the wireless mouse and keyboard?.

I have the screenshot of the `powertop` output below:

[image: powertop screenshot]

Comment: Two comments: 1. Not Bluetooth and 2. The only way to avoid it is by unplugging the dongle. And it' s using more energy precisely because the wireless devices aren't in range therefore the RF device increases its TX/RX power for a better chance of finding the devices it's supposed to work with.